# Dynamically change the height of a Slickgrid table

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

Is it possible to change the height of a slickgrid table after it's been rendered? Ideally with out having to destroy the grid and re-init.

It currently looks like once the grid is rendered, it doesn't change.

I've been using JQuery resizeable to resize the containing div.

Comment: Share with us, the code which you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Call `grid.resizeCanvas()` method after releasing the layout resizer grip.